# Attach an XML file to a PDF using Access 2016 VBA

Tags: vba, pdf-generation, digital-signature

I need to insert an XML file inside a PDF (as attachment) using Access VBA and I would like to find a solution without buying Acrobat.
Then I need to sing it digitally PAdES BES and save the file in PDF/A-3.
Is there some ideas or better some code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use our DynamicPDF Core Suite for COM/ActiveX v11 to achieve this. It supports embedding files in a PDF and digitally signing it with PAdES. Here is a VBA sample:

```
Dim MyDocument As DynamicPDF.Document
Dim MyPage As DynamicPDF.Page
Set MyDocument = New DynamicPDF.Document
MyDocument.LoadPdf ("C:\Input.pdf")
Set MyPage = MyDocument.GetPage(1)
Dim MyXmp As DynamicPDF.XmpMetaData

Set MyXmp = MyDocument.SetXmpMetaData
MyXmp.AddPdfASchema DPDF_PdfAStandard_PDF_A_3a

Dim MyEmbeddedFile
Set MyEmbeddedFile = MyDocument.AddEmbeddedFile("C:\XMLFile.xml", "")
MyEmbeddedFile.Relation = DPDF_EmbeddedFileRelation_Source
MyEmbeddedFile.MimeType = "application/xml"

Dim MySignature As DynamicPDF.Signature
Set MySignature = MyPage.AddSignature("SigField", 10, 10, 250, 100)
MySignature.Visible = True

Dim MyCertificate As DynamicPDF.Certificate
Set MyCertificate = MyDocument.DigitalSignatures.GetCertificate("C:\JohnDoe.pfx", "password")
MyCertificate.SignatureType = DPDF_SignatureType_PAdESBasic

MyDocument.Sign "SigField", MyCertificate
MyDocument.DrawToFile ("C:\Output.pdf")
```

You can find more information about DynamicPDF Core Suite for COM/ActiveX at the link below:

https://www.dynamicpdf.com/PDF-Suite-COM.aspx

Please note that you will need to use version 11 (currently available as a BETA version) to achieve this:

https://www.dynamicpdf.com/beta.aspx